# Yodlee Y400 error when trying to add providerAccount works on Windows but rarely on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, curl, yodlee

So I ended up trying to debug this issue from the command line by using curl. On my linux machine I receive "[errorCode] => Y400 [errorMessage] => Null argument specified".

This is the curl command I'm using, but with the missing information filled in:

```
curl -v --insecure -i -H "Authorization: {cobSession=cobSessionHere,userSession=userSessionHere}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"field\":[{\"id\":loginFieldId,\"value\":\"login\"},{\"id\":passwordFieldId,\"value\":\"password\"}]}" https://developer.api.yodlee.com/ysl/restserver/v1/providerAccounts?providerId=providerId
```

On my windows machine, the api call executes successfully. Same version of curl, same build, same verbose output. The only difference being that on the linux machine, the server sends me "400 Bad Request" then the error message I mentioned above.

Very rarely, sometimes it will work on the linux machine.

Is there any sort of curl configuration I can check or maybe a network policy in place that I could change to potentially fix this issue? Or is this most likely on Yodlee's end?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming-related questions. If you are unsure about *curl* command-line utility usage, [SuperUser @ SE](http://superuser.com) may be a better place to ask. If you need help in managing server-side application, [ServerFault @ SE](http://serverfault.com) may fit better.

Comment: Well since my php code uses curl, I figured it was okay to ask as that's where the problem originated. I know how to use curl. I see a lot of people posting questions about yodlee's api here and not providing any code so I figured it was alright to inquire.

Comment: In most cases on StackOverflow, “no code” means “no question”. If *your* code is responsible (or is supposed to be responsible) for checking that an argument is specified and/or otherwise valid, you should definitely attach that code or a minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: The only reason I'm posting here is there's a StackOverflow link in Yodlee's "developer" portal StackOverflow is apparently the only support they offer. If they offered a support ticketing system of some kind, I wouldn't be here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not passed the HTTP method- POST, that is why you have got bad request

Please use the sample curl command for adding an account-

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: cobSession=sessionValuehere,userSession=sessionValue" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "loginForm": {
    "row": [{
      "field": [{
        "id": 65499,
        "value": "sampleapp.site16441.2"
       }]
     },
     {
      "field": [{
        "id": 65500,
        "value": "site16441.2"
       }]
     }]
  }
}' "https://developer.api.yodlee.com/ysl/restserver/v1/providers/providerAccounts?providerId=16441"
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik